# Lauch of EC2 Intance and attach to Target Group using Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to launch EC2 instance and attachig to Target group using following code in lambda function But i am getting following error. But lambda funciton not getting Intsance ID and giving and error, please guide

Error is:

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the RegisterTargets operation: Instance ID 'instance_id' is not valid",
  "errorType": "ClientError",
```

Code is :

```
import boto3
import json
import time 
import os

AMI = 'ami-047a51fa27710816e'
INSTANCE_TYPE = os.environ['MyInstanceType'] 
KEY_NAME = 'miankeyp'
REGION = 'us-east-1'


ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=REGION)


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    instance = ec2.run_instances(
        ImageId=AMI,
        InstanceType=INSTANCE_TYPE,
        KeyName=KEY_NAME,
        MaxCount=1,
        MinCount=1
    )
    
    print ("New instance created:")
    instance_id = instance['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']
    print (instance_id)

    client=boto3.client('elbv2')
    time.sleep(5)
    response = client.register_targets(
        TargetGroupArn='arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1::targetgroup/target-demo/c46e6bfc00b6886f',
        Targets=[
           {
            'Id': 'instance_id'
           },
        ]
   )
```

Comment: You've put quotes around `'instance_id'`, I think you mean `instance_id`.

Comment: Yes its working removing quotes, but now another issue, Instance should be in running state to attach to target group. time sleep function not working. tried after increasing to 15

Comment: If you have another question then you must create another post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To wait until an instance is running, you can use an [Instance State waiter](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.InstanceRunning).

This is a boto3 capability that will check the state of an instance every 15 seconds until it reaches the desired state, up to a limit of 40 checks, which allows 10 minutes.